# Codeignighter Shopping cart issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I'm writing a small shopping **cart** facility on top of the `codeignighter` framework.
Using the built in cart Class, I want to update a products price that has already being added to the cart.

This is similar to a coupon at the checkout point. I'm offering $5 off the current price of a particular product.

To me the code below looks ok but it's not updating the prices.

Anyone know why?

```
 foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item) {
      if($item['id'] == 1) {
          $item['price'] = $item['price'] - 5;
          $this->cart->update($item);
      }

 }
```

Comment: Well, is the product id 1? var_dump $item to see if you're checking the right ID

Comment: Yeah I always var_dump(). The data being passed is good

Comment: Your using items['price'] instead of $item, unless thats a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the cart->update function to work, you need to pass the rowid to it. Try:

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) {
      if($items['id'] == 1) {
          $rowid = $items['rowid'];

          $data = array(
             'rowid' => $rowid,
             'price' => $items['price']-5
          );
          $this->cart->update($data);
      }

 }
```

Comment: Its strange, im able to change the QTY but not the price. Is this (calculation)internally handled by the Cart class maybe.

Comment: Seems that there is a limitation to the cart itself, only to update the quantity of product. You need to extend the library to be able to update an item s price. Take a look here: https://bitbucket.org/nelson.wells/extended-codeigniter-cart/src/b9d1601be11a7044d54243ffe9470ce4f9f42728/application/libraries/MY_Cart.php?at=default

Comment: Thankyou, I dug down  and found the source for the cart class and found this line too :   ((This function permits the quantity of a given item to be changed. ))

Comment: Thx Mallix. Just what I needed.